Why do I sometimes get a speed boost when shooting?
Sometimes when I shoot my gun in Neon While I'll get a boost of speed with line effects on the side of the screen. However, this only happens occasionally at inconsistent times. Why do I sometimes get a speed boost when shooting?

You get a speed boost when destroying enemy projectiles with a gun or parrying them with your sword. You also get a speed boost for shooting your own projectiles such as rockets and purify bombs.
This is confirmed by several posts online.
